# Set fix font size for all textview inside relative layout

Tags: android

I have `textviews` inside third party component and the parent container for this is `RelativeLayout`.Is there any way to programmatically set all `Textview` Text Size to be static I mean not change when the user uses Big fonts or big zoom from his phone settings

Answer (score 1):

**Scale-independent Pixels - sp** means it is scaled by the user's font size preference.

**Density-independent Pixels - dp** is fixed size mainly used for Layouts.

If you need the same TextView size in different phone regardless of user font size preference then you should use **dp**.

Use this,

```
 textView.setTextSize( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, intSize);
```

But sp is recommended for TextView

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,14);
```

Comment: this is what he tries to avoid, SP respects user font settings